# Is this a GCC bug like learncpp.com claims?

Tags: c++, gcc, c-strings, compiler-bug

In C++ learning website (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-9a-dynamically-allocating-arrays/) there is a claim that GCC has a bug related to C-style string initialization when new operator is involved:

> As of the time of writing, the GCC still has a bug where initializing a dynamically allocated array of chars using a C-style string literal causes a compiler error:
>
> ```
> char *array = new char[14] { "Hello, world!" }; // doesn't work in GCC, though it should
> ```

I am using GCC version 7.4.0.

If I try to compile this excerpt I get:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
     char *array = new char[14] { "Hello, world!" };
```

If I try to compile code like this:

```
char *array = new char[14] {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}
```

then it works as expected.

I am assuming this is considered a bug since:

```
char array[14]{ "Hello, world!" };
```

works as expected.

I could not find more information on this. Can anybody confirm or deny that this is a GCC bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's a GCC bug. The relevant issue in the bug tracker is [77841](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77841). To quote the description over there:

> 5.3.4 New [expr.new] p.17.2
>   Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.
>
> 8.5 Initializers [dcl.init] p.17.1
>   If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
>
> 8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list] p.3.2
>   Otherwise, if T is a character array and the initializer list has a single element that is an appropriately-typed string literal (8.5.2), initialization is performed as described in that section.

So the new expression in your question should be well-formed, just like the direct-initialization of the array object.

No prediction on when it's gonna be fixed. It's still [reproducible in GCC's trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/EyoNpY) as of writing this.

Comment: Look like [C++17 Standard - 11.6 Initializers(p12)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4741.pdf#section.11.6) in the C++17 standard also applies and initializers for dynamically allocated objects are treated no differently.